# PL/pgSQL: How to get variable's / parameter's name? [postgresql]

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_function(test_parameter varchar default 'test_value_1')
    RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
    test_variable varchar = 'test_value_2';
BEGIN
    raise notice '% = %', (???), test_parameter; -- expected result: test_parameter = test_value_1
    raise notice '% = %', (???), test_variable;  -- expected result: test_variable = test_value_2
    return;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM public.test_function();
```

How can be obtained a variable's / parameter's name in PostgreSQL (PL/pgSQL)?

Comment: You do not.  Use the variable name inside the notice template, e.g. `raise notice 'test_parameter = %', test_parameter`

Answer (score 0):

Either make the variable name part of the template or pass it as a string:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_function(test_parameter varchar default 'test_value_1')
    RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
    test_variable varchar = 'test_value_2';
BEGIN
    raise notice '% = %', 'test_parameter', test_parameter; -- expected result: test_parameter = test_value_1
    raise notice 'test_variable = %', test_variable;  -- expected result: test_variable = test_value_2
    return;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM public.test_function();
```

Answer (score 0):

Some languages passing function arguments as dictionary object (like Python). Arguments in Postgres environment are passed as a array of values (and this array is not accessible from PLpgSQL). Names can be taken from system table `pg_proc`, but it is slow and not trivial to read these data in plpgsql. Philosophy of working with arguments or variables in PLpgSQL is same like static compiled languages C, C++, Pascal, Ada, ... You cannot to get list of variables or arguments inside function in runtime. This information doesn't exist in compiled code or it is not accessible from language (PLpgSQL).